# Powermail Email to friend

Tags: typo3, typoscript, powermail

I want to create an 'Email to friend' form where the user enters an email address, and an email is sent to that address with a link to the current page url.

How do I set the receiver to be the email entered into the form?

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.email = TEXT
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.receiver.overwrite.email.data = myemailfield??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.data = GP:tx_powermail_pi1|field|markername`
But beware that your system can send emails to any email address that a user wants. Someone could use it for spaming with a "tipafriend" function.

Comment: Do you know if there a way to avoid this kind of spammer? Perhaps an email limit per ip?